# How to connect a part of a component without interfering with another part of the same component in Altium?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

The following is part B of an F4 MCU (the power supply part). I connected the circuitry and I would like to switch to part A to carry on the design of my schematics.

[image]

The following is Part A, as you can see I can't hide Part B's circuitry to connect the remaining component to Part A.

When I try to move Part A, Part B is still connected and messes up the connections of Part B. How can I hide the entire Part B schematic when switching to Part A? Or can I dissociate them?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "switch to part A/B"? This component has two parts. Both are placed somewhere in your schematics. You connect both of them.

Comment: @asdfex Thanks, this MCU has two parts, right-click > properties, you can choose to work with either part A or Part B, but not both at the same time. They are not both on the schematic.

Comment: Place the A part. SHIFT+DRAG it. You will have a B part under the cursor. Place it.

Comment: @TimWilliams This is it, thanks bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to TimWilliams, "Place the A part. SHIFT+DRAG it. You will have a B part under the cursor. Place it."